# why my baked texture is half black blender 2.9

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking

I have a texture for a shirt and when I render it the image texture is black. The shirt has a sweater on top of it maybe that explains it a little bit. How can I fix this problem?
[image: texture]

Comment: could you please pack the images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I agree with moonboots, and it looks like AO is way too high